# validação para PartialView

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Tenho uma página que chama uma partialview formada por uma div com campo texto para dentro dela, através de um botão. Cada vez que o botão é apertado é adicionada uma linha. O problema é que eu não consigo validar os campos vazios dessa partialview.

Eu uso o `@Html.ValidationMessageFor`

**Minha View**

```
@model CondicaoPagamentoDiasViewModel

@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("CondicaoPagamentoDiass"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CondicaoPagamentoDiasId)
        <label class="col-md-1 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="col-md-1">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dias, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control prazo" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dias, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/excluir.png")" onclick="$(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();" style="cursor:pointer;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_ValidationMaskPartial"); }
```

**Minha PartialView**

```
<div style="margin: 0 0 0 102px;" id="condicoes-pagamento" name="condicoes-pagamento">
                                @if (Model != null)
                                {
                                    foreach (var condicoesPgto in Model.CondicaoPagamentoDiass)
                                    {
                                        @Html.Partial("_CondicoesPagamentoDia", condicoesPgto);
                                    }
                                }
                            </div>
```

chamo ela aqui. Só quero validar os campos dela como tem na página principal.

Comment: Você quer validar os campos da partial **_CondicoesPagamentoDia**?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Quero validar como na principal, nela eu tenho uma igual e ela valida.

Comment: Você está fazendo validação por **Data Annotation**? Se sim, pode sua entidade com as anotações.

Comment: Não, uso o @Html.ValidationMessageFor, isso colocado na ViewModel.

Comment: Sim, mas você está decorando sua `ViewModel` com alguma anotação? `[Required]`, `[StringLength()]`, etc. Ou utilizando [EF Fluent API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617.aspx#1.5). Validação por `jQuery`? O que está utilizando para isso?

Comment: Estou usando [Required] mesmo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu pesquisei e achei a seguinte solução colocada na **PartialView**, na parte de `scripts`, funcionou direitinho:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("form").removeData("validator").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
</script>
```

Comment: Não entendi. Por que a validação unobtrusiva estaria atrapalhando?

Comment: Não entendi Cigano, eu procurei essa solução e funcionou para o que eu queria fazer. unobstrusiva não está atrapalhando.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei como está sua *ViewModel*, mas é preciso anotar [`[Required]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) nas propriedades que não podem ser vazias para a validação correta:

```
[Required]
public int Dias { get; set; }
```

Opcionalmente, você pode fazer com que o JavaScript valide o formulário pra você antes do `POST`, inserindo o seguinte na *View*:

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

É importante forçar a validação em *Controller* também. Isto pode ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid) { ... }
```

Comment: Cigano na minha ViewModel tem o [Required], mas mesmo assim ele não esta validando a Partial.

Comment: @jp_almeida Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Cigano a minha controller já possui esse if.

Comment: Então não sei o que é.

Comment: Cigano no If(modelState.isvalid) ele não passa quando está vazio, será que posso aproveitar isso e fazer a validação? Tem como?

Comment: Sim, você pode não validar quando estiver vazio.

Comment: Mas fazer a validação normal não tem como nesse else depois do if, como acontece nos da página principal? Eu falo a mensagem.